# Pequeno problema com paginação PHP puro

Tags: php, mysql, paginação

Olá, eu tenho a seguinte função que faz a paginação conforme o que o usuario digitou no input de pesquisa:

```
function pesquisar($botao, $input, $conteudo)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$botao]) || $_GET['pagina'])
    {
        $busca = $_POST[$input]; // pega os dados que estao no campo para a pesquisa
        $busca_divida = explode(',', $busca); // divide o que esta no campo por virgulas
        $quant =  count($busca_divida); // total de itens a serem pesquisados
        
        $id_mostrado = array(""); 
        $p = $_GET["pagina"]; // vai por isto na url

        if(isset($p)) // verifica se está setado na url  
        {
            $p = $p; // se sim a pagina recebe o que ela tem
        } 
        else 
        {
            $p = 1; // se nao ela recebe 1
        }

        $qnt = 10; // maximo de conteudo exibido por página
        $inicio = ($p*$qnt) - $qnt; // calcula quantas páginas serão necessárias conforme o numero de itens por página x itens do banco 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbnews WHERE ".$conteudo." LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%' and publicar = 'Y' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT $inicio, $qnt  " ); 
        $quant_campos = mysql_num_rows($sql); // cria uma variavel com o total de linhas no banco que correspondem a pesquisa
        for($i = 0; $i < $quant ; $i++)
        {
            $pesquisa = $busca_divida[$i]; // para cada item do campo, faz um laço para percorrer e trazer o dado
            if($quant_campos == 0)
            {
                echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado"; // se nao encontrar nada
            }
            else
            {
                while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) // se encontrar imprime eles na tela
                {
                    $id = $linha['id'];
                    $titulo = $linha['titulo'];
                    $tags = $linha['tags'];
                    $data = $linha['data'];
                    $imagem = $linha['imagem'];
                    $apoio = $linha['apoio'];
                    $tipo = $linha['tipo'];
                    if ($tipo == 'I'){
                        $tipo = 24;
                    }
                    if ($tipo == 'G'){
                        $tipo = 56;
                    }
                    if(!array_search($id, $id_mostrado))
                    {

                    $imageThumb = "<a href='index.php?idConteudo=".$tipo."&idNoticia=".$id."' "
                                . "style='display:block; ]"
                                . "background-image:URL(common/thumb.php?src=../upload/noticias/".$imagem."&h=110&w=110); "
                                . "background-position:center; "
                                . "background-repeat:no-repeat; "
                                . "width:82px; "
                                . "height:82px; "
                                . "margin-right:10px; "
                                . "float:left;'>    </a>";

                    $itemPrincipal = "".$imageThumb."<a href='index.php?idConteudo=".$tipo."&idNoticia=".$id."'>"
                                   . "<h4 class='tituloListagem'>".$titulo."</h4> \n"
                                   . "<h6 class='apoioListagem'>".$apoio."</h6> \n"
                                   . "<span style='font-size:x-small; "
                                   . "display:block; "
                                   . "margin-top:3px; "
                                   . "font-weight:normal;'> ".$data." </span> </a>"
                                   . "<span style='font-size:x-small; "
                                   . "display:block; "
                                   . "margin-top:3px; "
                                   . "font-weight:normal;'><b>Palavras-Chave:</b> ".$tags." </span> </a>"
                                   . "<a href='?idConteudo=".$tipo."&idNoticia=".$id."'> <nobr> Leia mais...</nobr> </a> </p>";


                    echo $itemPrincipal;
                    array_push($id_mostrado, $id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
        
        $sql_select_all = "SELECT * FROM tbnews WHERE ".$conteudo." LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%' and publicar = 'Y' ORDER BY data DESC "; // faz o mesmo select 
        $sql_query_all = mysql_query($sql_select_all); // executa a query
        $total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_query_all); // conta quantos itens tem 
        $pags = ceil($total_registros/$qnt); // calcula quantas páginas terá e arredonda para cima. 
        $max_links = 3; //quantas páginas irão aparecer ao redor da página atual na paginação.
        
        echo '<a href="pesquisar.php?pagina=1" target="_self"> << </a>&nbsp;&nbsp'; // primeira pagina

        for($i = $p-$max_links; $i <= $p-1; $i++) 
        {
            if($i > 0) 
            {
                echo '<a href="pesquisar.php?pagina='.$i.'"" target="_self">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp'; // paginas anteriores
            } 
        }

        echo " <b>".$p."</b>&nbsp;&nbsp "; // pagina atual

        for($i = $p+1; $i <= $p+$max_links; $i++) 
        {
            if($i < $pags)
            {
                echo '<a href="pesquisar.php?pagina='.$i.'"" target="_self">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp'; // paginas posteriores
            }
        }
        echo '<a href="pesquisar.php?pagina='.$pags.'""" target="_self"> >> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp'; // ultima pagina
}
```

A função faz uma verificação se os dados que irá carregar vem do input OU vem se conforme a ultima página da url;

a função funciona quase bem certo, só que ela imprime 2 vezes a parte da paginação. Um no começo da listagem e outro no final.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue uma imagem de como o código está sendo impresso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode colocar um print de como aparece?

Comment: Eu adicionei uma imagem agora com o que está sendo impresso pela função.

Comment: Ok vamos ver o que é

Comment: Não se trata de um pequeno problema, se trata de um "problemão". Se você adotasse as boas práticas de desenvolvimento, você entenderia que esse tipo de problema deveria ser superado de uma maneira mais simples, leia isso: http://www.php-fig.org/